# Difference between skew() and skewX() skewY()

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

While creating some transformations for some objects in my website I found the following.If an object is given the transformation property `skew(20deg,45deg)` will be different than an other object with `skewX(20deg)` and `skewY(45deg)`.

Can someone explain me why is this happening?

```css
.skew {
  height:10em;
  width:10em;
  background:red;
  margin:auto;
}

#first {
  transform:skew(20deg,45deg);
}

#second {
  transform:skewX(20deg) skewY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="skew" id="first"> skew(20deg,45deg) </div> <hr>
<div class="skew" id="second"> skewX(20deg) skewY(45deg) </div>
```

**Update:** skew has short syntax. How can I achieve the same effect I have with `skewX()` and `skewY()` by using `skew()` short syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thinking about matrix , when you do

```
 transform : skew(x, y);
```

then it is like cross multiplication of matrices

> [ X , Y, Z ]

and

```
| 1,  sx,  0 |
| sy,  1,  0 |
| 0,   0,  1 |
```

> where `sx = tan(x)` and `sy = tan(y)`

resulting in new coords

```
X' = X + Y * sx
Y' = Y + X * sy
Z' = Z
```

but when you do

```
transform : skewX(x) skewY(y);
```

it is like first cross multiply matrix

> [ X, Y, Z ]

with matrix

```
| 1, sx, 0 |
| 0,  1, 0 |
| 0,  0, 1 |
```

resulting in new coords

```
X' = X + Y * sx
Y' = Y
Z' = Z
```

and then new matrix

> [ X', Y', Z' ]

cross multiplied with

```
| 1,  0, 0 |
| sy, 1, 0 |
| 0,  0, 1 |
```

resulting in new coords as

```
X" = X + Y * sx
Y" = Y + ( X + Y * sx ) * sy
Z" = Z
```

thus the **Y** coords changes from `Y + X * sy` to `Y + ( X + Y * sx ) * sy`

Comment: This is the correct answer! The coords are changed before the second skew function.

Comment: @singhiskng Accepted.But i would appreciate if you can find me a way to a solve my problem since i have no idea about matrices.I am not so good at maths

Comment: i want to achieve the same results without using skewX and skewY but only the short syntax

Comment: @cssGEEK :- you mean short syntax by matrix style or something else

Comment: @cssGEEK :- for matrix manipulation i prefer you to go through this link http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#funcdef-skew

Comment: @cssGEEK :- it has nice explanation but little lengthy.

Answer (score 4):

As quoted on [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#funcdef-skew) :

> Note that the behavior of `skew()` is different from multiplying `skewX()`
>   with `skewY()`. Implementations must support this function for
>   compatibility with legacy content.

So just use `skew(x,y)` if you want to set both or just use `skewX()` or `skewY()` if you want to set a specific skew axis.

Also, logically it doesn't make any sense to use `skewX()` and `skewY()` on the same `transform` where you can use `skew()` alone to set both.

Comment: `transform` can accept any combination of any number of transform functions. Even the note that you quote says "multiplying `skewX()` with `skewY()`" which implies that you can indeed combine them into a single declaration. If you tried to specify two separate `transform` declarations, one would just override the other.

Comment: So I think it's an implementation issue here.

Answer (score 0):

CSS skew property has no short syntax:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

YOu have to use:

```
transform: skewX(value);  /* e.g. skewX(25deg) */
transform: skewY(value);
```

Comment: That blog post you've linked to 1. isn't an official resource, and 2. was created *before* the `skew` short syntax was added. Skew does have a short syntax: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't know that